# How do you make WebStorm highlight a Dockerfile.dev file as a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, ide, webstorm

I have two separate Dockerfile(s) for development and production, but WebStorm only highlights correctly the production Dockerfile (because it's called that, `Dockerfile`).

Is there any way of making the IDE understand that both should be highlighted (and hopefully linted) in the same way?

Thanks.

Comment: this is a difficult topic since the suffix tells also the content of the file. e.g. consider Dockerfile.go. What's going to be the correct syntax? Go or Dockerfile?

Comment: Dockerfile. I'm totally open to change the naming if it's causing problems.

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File types` -- locate file type entry for the Dockerfile and add your other/custom fiilename pattern there.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of webstorm (2023.2.2), you can simply right click the file and choose "Associate with File Type..."

[Menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USG3c.png)